# selectBooleanCheckbox 'onBlur' wrongfully called on page load instead of 'onBlur'

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem. I have page on my web app, with this code. When I show the page with this code, the onBlur method is call. How to solve it? At this time, I just want to display the element...not call the method. Thanks for tips :)

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{rec.mediated}" id="checkbox"
                         onblur="#{ViewBean.addRecToMed(rec, 'lI')}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{ViewBean.invalidate()}" update="@form" event="change"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation about the onblur events? Tried with a plain jsf component?

Comment: Yes, but I could have missed something

Comment: That is why [ask] states to keep track of what you tried and mention it in the question... The documentation has the answer (as several duplicates in stacloverflow which I'm currently searching)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This is definitely the solution I'm looking for.